# On Semistable sheaves on surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective surface (over $\mathbb C$). If $F$ is a semistable (Gieseker or slope) sheaf with respect to a very ample line bundle $H$ on $X$, then isn't it so that the definition of semistability requires that $F$ has to be pure of dimension $\text{dim}(F)$ and equivalently $F$ has to be torsion free? (please correct me if this equivalence part is wrong).

I ask this question because in many articles I have seen that it starts with the phrase 'Let $M$ be the moduli space of $H$ semistable torsion free sheaves with fixed rank and Chern classes on $X$' and if the argument in the previous paragraph is true, then the word torsion free is redundant in the description of $M$.

Any remark is welcome.